# C++/Qt how to declare and initialize a global array of objects

Tags: c++, qt, initialization, global-variables, declare

How can I make it a global arrays of objects, like QPoint point[5][6];

global.h

```
#include <QPoint>
extern QPoint point[5][6];//Am I correct？
```

global.cpp

`#include <global.h> // How to initialize???`

main.cpp

```
#include <global.h>
use them;
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend not to do this. The whole structure of the Qt libraries is object oriented; throwing globals in there makes the code hard to read and maintain, and error prone. Define the `QPoint` in the structure that needs it, and consider using `std::vector` or one of the Qt given containers instead of C style arrays

Comment: It's really hard to turn my mind from procedure-oriented mind.Do you have some good books or websites about object oriented mind and how to design good classes recommend to me .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list has some great book recommendations and for general design patterns [GoF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) is a good read, but that's not C++ specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Globals are evil. Alas, the idiomatic way to do it is:

1. Declare the global variable extern in a header file.
2. Define the variable in *one* source file (and no more). Include the declaration from the header to ensure the definition is correct.
3. Use the variable in any number of source files; include the declaration from the header.

`global.h`

```
#ifndef BENHUAN_GLOBAL_H_INCLUDED
#define BENHUAN_GLOBAL_H_INCLUDED
#include <QPoint>
extern QPoint point[5][6]; // declaration
#endif
```

`global.cpp`

```
#include "global.h'
QPoint point[5][6]; // definition
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "global.h"

...
   point[1][2] = QPoint(5,6);
```